# ng-model com valor indefinido no controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou com um problema bem estranho.Tenho alguns filtros que estão assim.

```
<div ng-show="filtroReduzido" class="col-md-2">
   <div class="form-group">
        <label>Codigo Reduzido</label>
           <div class="form-group form-md-line-input no-hint right" style="padding-top: 3px;">
             <select id="servico"  
                     name="servico"  
                     chosen  
                     width="150"
                     allow-single-deselect="true"
                     ng-model="vm.filtro.des_servico"
                     style="width:100%"
                     ng-options="clienteFiltro as cliente.Des_Servico for cliente in vm.importacaoSiltDet |unique:'Des_Servico'| orderBy:'Des_Servico'"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

No controller eu declaro o "filtro"

```
 vm.filtro = {};
```

Na minha function eu chamo essa `ng-model` porem ela vem `undifined`.
O dateDe e dateAte estão recebendo os parâmetros normalmente, e o `vm.relatorio` está declaro igual `vm.filtro`.

Não entendo o porque as variaveis `test2` e `test3` estão vindo `undifined`, estou esquecendo de alguma etapa? talvez dar um bind nos valores do parametros do filtro?

```
vm.filtrarDetFiltrado = function () {
            debugger;
            var dateDe = formatarData(vm.relatorio.dataDe);
            var dateAte = formatarData(vm.relatorio.dataAte);
            var test2 = vm.filtro.des_servico;
            var test3 = vm.filtro.Des_Servico;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tenta declarar inicialmente um valor para essa variável, ficando assim: `vm.filtro = { des_servico: null };`

Comment: Ele declarada ficando assim des_servico:undefined porem no var teste3 ele nao recebe o parametro do filtro.

Comment: Dá uma olhada no primeiro exemplo da documentação do Angular.. [AngularJS - Select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select), veja se te ajuda

Comment: Acho que encontrei o problema, estava no ng-options,mudei para  ng-options="cliente.Des_Servico for cliente in vm.importacaoSiltDet      porem agora ao invez de passar o valor do filtro esta passando o objeto da grid.

Comment: Coloquei assmi agora e funcionou   ng-options="cliente.Des_Servico as cliente.Des_Servico for cliente in vm.importacaoSiltDet

Comment: @ViniciusCano vc pode fazer uma resposta pro seu proprio post, pra ajudar futuras pessoas com a mesma duvida

Answer (score 0):

O problema estava no alias do ng-options, eu imaginava que não importava, porem o antigo estava

```
ng-options="clienteFiltro as cliente.Des_Servico for cliente in vm.importacaoSiltDet
```

Ele devia estar se perdendo no clienteFiltro, corrigi utilizando ng-options da seguinte maneira.

```
ng-options="cliente.Des_Servico as cliente.Des_Servico for cliente in vm.importacaoSiltDet
```